# Batch file how to call another batch file at a specified label or call and immediately goto a certain label?

Tags: label, call, batch-file

I am trying to figure out how file1.bat can call file2.bat at a specified label.

I figured I can do it like this:

*File1.bat*

```
:config
@echo off
:setvars
set labelmarker=labelmarker
call file2.bat
pause > nul
:EOF
```

*File2.bat*

```
if %labelmarker%==labelmarker goto label4
:label1
echo it won't work...
goto EOF
:label2
echo it must work!
goto EOF
:label3
echo it didn't work...
goto EOF
:label4
echo it works!
goto EOF
:EOF
```

This works. but I want to call a bat AND the Label from file1.bat.
is it possible with a control character or ascii code or anything?
like i tried

```
call file2.bat | goto label4 - doesn't work
call file2.bat > goto label4 - doesn't work
call file2.bat @label4 - doesn't work
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Even if it involves extracting a specific label and contents to a new file would be ok.

Comment: I thought it would work with `call file2.bat:label4` or something to that effect. Unfortunately, there seems to be no such possibility (except for hacking file2.bat, but this may sometimes be out of the question).

Answer (score 11):

You could pass the label you want to go to as a parameter

Example scripts

*First.bat*

```
@echo off
set label=GOHERE
call Second.bat %label%
pause >nul
```

*Second.bat*

```
@echo off
goto %1
echo This line should be skipped
:GOHERE
echo Jumped here
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a **strange trick**!
You can *goto* a label in a secondary batch without calling it in the secondary batch!

*First.bat*

```
@echo off
call :label
echo returned
exit /b

:label
second.bat
exit /b
```

*Second.bat*

```
@echo off
echo Main of second.bat
exit /b

:label
echo This is second.bat at LABEL
exit /b
```

*OUTPUT*

```
This is second.bat at LABEL
returned
```

There seems to be no cause why the label is called, nor why the control should return to the *first.bat*, as second batch was *called* without a *CALL*.
The cause for the first point seems to be the internal code of the `goto` command.
The second point can be explained, as there is one call prior to the *dummy* label in the first batch file.
The `exit /b` in second.bat returns directly to the call (line 3) of `first.bat` not to the invocation of `second.bat` at line 7

**EDIT:** How to disable the odd behaviour

if you append a command at `second.bat` it will no longer implicit jump to the label in *second.bat*.

`second.bat & rem` will change the output to
*OUTPUT*

```
Main of second.bat
returned
```

Comment: +1, I had completely forgotten about that bizarre behavior. Good memory.

Comment: @dbenham, I found a way to disable it, with a `& REM`

Comment: Interesting. It is also disabled if the "call" is enclosed in parentheses - `(second.bat)`

Comment: may I add a trick I have been using for quite some time now: `second.bat %*`

add %* after second.bat and the holy grail of arguments will bow to you.

If you dont, arguments will not be passed. Both share the same behaviour. However, you can strip arguments this way ("cleaning" the call, can be usefull for cycle calls)

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods or tricks that allows to do this. In this solution the trick consists in *change the context* of the running program to the second Batch file. After this change, all labels in the second Batch file becomes *local labels* of the running program, so they may be directly called via the usual `call :label` command that may also include arguments in an entirely standard way. The context of the running program must be recovered before the program terminates.

The way to change the context consist is just *rename* the second Batch file with the same name of the first one (and rename the first one to any other name) so when the Batch file processor looks for a label, it really search the contents of the second file! The files must be renamed back to their original names before the program terminate. The key point that makes this method work is that both sets of rename commands (and all code between them) must be *enclosed in parentheses*; in this way, the code is first parsed and then executed *from memory*, so the rename of the files on disk don't affect it. Of course, this point means that the access to the values of all variables in the code must be done via delayed !expansion! (or using the `call %%variable%%` trick).

*First.bat*

```
@echo off

rem Change the running context to the second/library batch file:
(
ren first.bat temporary.bat
ren second.bat first.bat

rem From this point on, you may call any label in second.bat like if it was a local label

call :label2
echo Returned from :label2
call :label1
echo Returned from :label1

rem Recover the running context to the original batch file
ren first.bat second.bat
ren temporary.bat first.bat
)

echo This is first.bat ending...
pause > nul
```

*Second.bat*

```
@echo off

:label1
echo I am label1 subroutine at second.bat
goto :EOF

:label2
echo This is the second subroutine at second.bat
goto :EOF
```

*OUTPUT*

```
This is the second subroutine at second.bat
Returned from :label2
I am label1 subroutine at second.bat
Returned from :label1
This is first.bat ending...
```

You should note that this method allows to *develop the subroutines* in the first file in the usual way (with no context change) and then just move the completed subroutines to the second/library file, because the way to call them is *exactly the same* in both cases. This method does not require any change in the second/library file nor in the way the subroutines are called; it just needs to insert the two small blocks of rename commands in the first file.

---

**EDIT**: *Restoring files when a run-time error happen*

As indicated in a comment, if a run-time error happen after the files were renamed, the files are not renamed back to their original names; however, it is very easy to detect this situation by the presence of the second.bat file and restore the files if such a file does not exists. This test may be done in a supervisor section that run the original code in a separate cmd.exe context, so this section will always complete correctly even if the original code was cancelled by an error.

*First.bat*

```
@echo off

if "%~1" equ "Original" goto Original

rem This supervisor section run the original code in a separate cmd.exe context
rem and restore the files if an error happened in the original code
(
cmd /C "%~F0" Original
if not exist second.bat (
   echo Error detected!  Restoring files
   ren first.bat second.bat & ren temporary.bat first.bat
)
goto :EOF
)


:Original

( ren first.bat temporary.bat & ren second.bat first.bat

call :label1
echo Returned from :label1
call :label2
echo Returned from :label2

ren first.bat second.bat & ren temporary.bat first.bat )

echo This is first.bat ending...
```

*Second.bat*

```
@echo off

:label1
echo I am label1 subroutine at second.bat
exit /B

:label2
set "var="
if %var% equ X echo This line cause a run-time error!
exit /B
```

*OUTPUT*

```
I am label1 subroutine at second.bat
Returned from :label1
No se esperaba X en este momento.
Error detected!  Restoring files
```

Comment: strange thing... But makes sense, if you think about it. Maybe a note about needed delayed expansion (inside the block) would be helpful.

Comment: @Stephan: good point. I added it. What about an upvote? **`:)`**

Comment: I upvoted it as the concept is cool. But your solution has drawbacks when an error occours, as then the files won't be restored

Answer (score 1):

I just created a script that might prove useful to you. I think it's strength is that you don't have to modify your called script in any way. I'm sure with a bit of time you can perfect it and make it fit your purpose. I also can figure that it isn't fast enough for production use when the called script is large. This method consists on placing my script to the folder of your own scripts, and using it like so:

**EDIT**

Now this script works from any directory and can be input with either full or relative paths to the called script, with or without file extension (C:\scripts\script, C:\scripts\script.bat, .\scripts\script.cmd, etc)

### Usage:

Given a sample script *script.bat*:

```
:LABEL_1
ECHO This is label number one!
GOTO :EOF

:LABEL_2
ECHO This is label number two!
GOTO :EOF
```

The following input:

```
CALLAT script :LABEL_2
```

Should output:

```
This is label number two!
```

### Source code of *CALLAT.bat*:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@ECHO OFF

rem Create a folder in the temporary files directory
MKDIR "%TEMP%\CALLAT\"> NUL

rem Chose a name for a temporal script
SET TEMP_SCRIPT="%TEMP%\CALLAT\temp-script.bat"

rem Get the full path to the called script
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /B /S "%1*" 2^>NUL') DO SET ORIGINAL_SCRIPT=%%F

rem Add this lines to go directly to the desired label in the temp script
ECHO @ECHO OFF> %TEMP_SCRIPT%
ECHO GOTO %2>> %TEMP_SCRIPT%

rem Concatenate the called script to the end of the temp script
COPY /B %TEMP_SCRIPT%+%ORIGINAL_SCRIPT% %TEMP_SCRIPT%>NUL

rem Call the modified script
CALL %TEMP_SCRIPT%

rem Clean up
RD "%TEMP%\CALLAT\" /S /Q>NUL

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer with a condition and an improvement. The condition is that the second IF statement is incorrect, because it repeats the first one. The improvements are that, as written, the script fails when you pass in a complete file name (extension and all), it doesn't clean up after itself, and it can replace the loop with a concatenation copy. Please see my next "answer" for more.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment that I attached to my answer, I awarded the bounty, because @NicoBerrogorry took the time to devise an excellent solution, and provide a complete write-up.

Nevertheless, there was one syntax error that he overlooked, probably because he doesn't use **CMD** files, while I have almost entirely abandoned **BAT** files. The following CALLAT script incorporates one correction and four enhancements.

1. It handles fully specified commands, that is, commands that specify the file name **with** its extension.
2. It corrects the oversight in the original that caused it to ignore **CMD** files.
3. When the target file simply cannot be found, it displays an error message.
4. The **for** loop that appends the file one line at a time is replaced with a decidedly old-school **COPY** command that appends the target script file to the two-line preamble that makes the whole thing work. In case you have forgotten or didn't know about it, the  **> NUL:** at the end of the copy command discards the "1 file copied" message.
5. While the original fulfilled its mission, it didn't clean up after itself; this version does so, by removing the temporary script file and the temporary directory in which it is created.

```html
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a folder in the temporary files directory.
IF NOT EXIST "%TEMP%\CALLAT\" MKDIR "%TEMP%\CALLAT\"

rem Chose a name for the modified script.
SET MODIFIED_SCRIPT="%TEMP%\CALLAT\modified_%1.bat"

rem Convert the called script name to the corresponding .bat
rem or .cmd full path to the called script.

rem Then load the script. - 2017/05/08 - DAG - The second if exist test duplicated the first. Instead, it must evaluate for the .CMD extension.

SET "COMMAND_FILE=%~dp0%1"
IF EXIST "%COMMAND_FILE%.bat" (
    SET "COMMAND_FILE=%COMMAND_FILE%.bat"
) ELSE IF EXIST "%COMMAND_FILE%.cmd" (
    SET "COMMAND_FILE=%COMMAND_FILE%.cmd"
) else if exist "%COMMAND_FILE%" (
 echo INFO: Using "%COMMAND_FILE%"
) else (
 echo ERROR: Cannot find script file %COMMAND_FILE%.bat
 echo                             or %COMMAND_FILE%.cmd
)

rem Add some lines to go directly to the desired label.
ECHO @ECHO OFF> %MODIFIED_SCRIPT%
ECHO GOTO %2>> %MODIFIED_SCRIPT%

rem Append the called script.
copy %MODIFIED_SCRIPT%+%COMMAND_FILE% %MODIFIED_SCRIPT% > NUL:

rem Call the modified script.
CALL %MODIFIED_SCRIPT%

rem Pack out your trash. When a script ends, you get an ENDLOCAL for free.
del %MODIFIED_SCRIPT%
rd "%TEMP%\CALLAT\"
```

Finally, this version of **CALLAT** eliminates a redundant **ECHO OFF** and the concluding **ENDLOCAL**, which I discovered long ago is unnecessary, because exiting a script implies **ENDLOCAL**.

Since virtually all of my production scripts inhabit a single directory that is accessible via the PATH directory list, the requirement that both scripts inhabit the same directory isn't a significant hindrance. Moreover, with a little more work, it could almost certainly be relaxed. I'll leave that as an exercise for interested readers, but I'll give you one clue; it might involve calling an internal subroutine that can parse the name of the input file by leveraging the technique described [in Command Line Parameters].[1](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)

The script shown above is about to find its way into production.

Comment: Hi, thank you and I'm glad I could help. I was just about posting my edit following your corrections. I've resolved the "finding the full path to the script" part in a different way, but I've done the concatenation part it the same way. I'll post my edit anyways just to show that I've tried to incorporate your corrections.