# Call subroutine inside another batch file that has spaces in the filename?

Tags: batch-file, call, space, subroutine

I've been looking at some examples on how to call a subroutine inside another batch file (i.e. [Call a subroutine in a batch from another batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168091/call-a-subroutine-in-a-batch-from-another-batch-file)), but somehow the external batch file is executed in the regular way i.e. from beginning to end, with the called function ignored/skipped.

I think it has to do something with the spaces in the external batch file:

```cmd
:: main batch file.cmd where the subroutine is called from
CALL "second batch file.cmd" :SUBROUTINE
goto :EOF
```

and:

```cmd
:: second batch file.cmd contents

ECHO IGNORE THIS
goto :EOF

:SUBROUTINE
ECHO SUBROUTINE CALLED FROM 'main batch file.cmd'!
goto :EOF
```

Isn't this supposed to work?

Comment: I think you have some concepts mixed up. This line: `CALL "second batch file.cmd" :SUBROUTINE` mean to call an external Batch file called "second batch file.cmd" with the `:SUBROUTINE` string passed in the first parameter. Such a string may be get inside the called Batch file via `%1` characters, as usual. The first parameter of the Batch file have _no relation_ with a `:SUBROUTINE` label in such a file, unless you start the called Batch file with `goto %1` command. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576270/batch-file-how-to-call-another-batch-file-at-a-specified-label-or-call-and-immed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter as the first line of the second batch file:

```
IF "%1"==":SUBROUTINE" GOTO :SUBROUTINE
```

Comment: I've been using this method in some of my batch files, but assumed it should also work using the method that i showed above. Because you gave a working example, i've marked your answer as solution. Thank you thx1138v2 ;-)